# Python queue block timeout does not timeout - any idea why?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I expect the following python code will print "Timeout:" in the console output.

It has a thread that produce objects.  The consumer thread will get the queued objects and print it out.

The expected Queue Get() timeout  is not happening.  Any idea on why?

**The output is: (No expected "Timeout: " printout.)**

```
1390521788.42  Outputting: o={'test': 2, 'sName': 't1'} 
1390521791.42  Outputting: o={'test': 3, 'sName': 't1'}
1390521794.42  Outputting: o={'test': 4, 'sName': 't1'}
1390521797.42  Outputting: o={'test': 5, 'sName': 't1'}
end while sName=t1
```

**This is tested with Python 2.7 in Linux.**

```
import threading, Queue, time

class ProduceThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__ (self, start_num, end, q, sName, nSleep=1):
        self.num = start_num
        self.q = q
        threading.Thread.__init__ (self)
        self.m_end = end;
        self.m_sName = sName;
        self.m_nSleep = nSleep;

    def run(self):
        o = {};
        o['sName'] = self.m_sName;
        while True:
            if self.num != self.m_end:
                self.num += 1
                o['test'] = self.num;
                # self.q.put(self.num)
                self.q.put(o)
                time.sleep(self.m_nSleep)
            else:
                break
        print "end while sName=%s" % (self.m_sName);

myQueue = Queue.Queue()
myThread = ProduceThread(1, 5, myQueue, 't1', 3); myThread.start()
# myThread2 = ProduceThread(1, 5, myQueue, 't2', 3); myThread2.start()
# myThread3 = ProduceThread(1, 5, myQueue, 't3', 3); myThread3.start()

def Log(s):
    t = time.time();
    print "%s  %s" %(t, s)

################################################################
#  Consumer Loop
while True:
    if not myQueue.empty():
        try:
            o = myQueue.get(block=True, timeout=1)
            Log( "Outputting: o=%s" % (o));
        except:
            ###### I expect the Timeout to happen here. But it is not.
            Log( "Timeout: " );
            pass;
    # time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about what's happening?  What's not happening that you expect to happen?  What's happening that you don't expect to happen? Or maybe show the output you get, and the output you expect?

Comment: Here are the output I saw:  (I expect some Timeout: printout
....
[code]
end while sName=t1
[code]
1390516345.73  Outputting: o={'test': 4, 'sName': 't2'}
1390516345.73  Outputting: o={'test': 4, 'sName': 't4'}
1390516348.73  Outputting: o={'test': 5, 'sName': 't2'}
1390516348.73  Outputting: o={'test': 5, 'sName': 't4'}
end while sName=t2
end while sName=t4

Comment: Are you intending to replace the original `myThread2` with the third thread, so you no longer have a name for the second thread? I don't think that's causing your problem, but it's certainly a red flag…

Comment: @user3203478: Don't try to put formatted data into comments. Besides, any information which is critical to understanding your question needs to be part of the question. So, edit the question.

Comment: As a side note, spinning as fast as possible around a non-blocking call like `empty()` guarantees that you're going to burn 100% CPU, and causes unnecessary GIL contention for all of the background threads. How do you avoid that? Loop over a blocking call like `get()` instead. Which would also make your code simpler—and, not coincidentally, solve the problem you're trying to solve to boot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, think about this:

```
if not myQueue.empty():
    try:
        o = myQueue.get(block=True, timeout=2)
        Log( "Outputting: o=%s" % (o));
```

Leave aside that you should never *rely* on the `Queue.empty()` method.  See the docs:

> If empty() returns True it doesn’t guarantee that a subsequent call to put() will not block. Similarly, if empty() returns False it doesn’t guarantee that a subsequent call to get() will not block.

However, in a context this simple, it's "pretty reliable" ;-)  Now how could your timeout possibly occur?  If and only if the `.get()` attempt is made when your queue is **empty**.  But you never execute your `.get()` when your queue is empty, because of your:

```
if not myQueue.empty():
```

test!  In effect, you're asking this:

> I only try to do .get() when I'm sure something is on the queue.  So I'm sure .get() will succeed immediatey.  So why doesn't it ever time out?

Remove the

```
if not myQueue.empty():
```

statement entirely and then it will eventually time out.

Comment: Pretty clever; instead of code that works except when there's a very rare race condition, he's written code that _fails_ except when there's a very rare race condition, which is a lot easier to debug. :)